# Basic Python StringIO -- Why is GetValue() Returning Nothing?

Tags: python, stringio

I'm having basic python issues.. In the following example no errors are returned but displaying the contents of all variables using pprint shows that *contents* is = '' -- why would this possibly be the case?

```
import sys, os, re, StringIO, pprint, time
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, BeautifulStoneSoup
import pycurl

url = "http://google.com/";

strio = StringIO.StringIO()

curlobj = pycurl.Curl()
curlobj.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
curlobj.perform()
curlobj.close()

contents = strio.getvalue()
strio.close()
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Look at the lines that involve `StringIO`.

```
strio = StringIO.StringIO()
contents = strio.getvalue()
strio.close()
```

None of these statements draw content from `curlobj`. So `strio` is empty.

---

Edit (thanks to @Alexander Cameron and @agf):

Perhaps you meant

```
curlobj.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, strio.write)
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like strio = StringIO.StringIO()

curlobj = pycurl.Curl()
curlobj.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
curlobj.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, strio.write)
curlobj.perform()
curlobj.close()

contents = strio.getvalue()
strio.close() is the way to do it.

Comment: or `curlobj.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, strio.write)`

Answer (score 2):

You never do anything with your `strio` variable. You have to pass it in to some function in order for anything to get written to it.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like strio = StringIO.StringIO()

curlobj = pycurl.Curl()
curlobj.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
curlobj.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, strio.write)
curlobj.perform()
curlobj.close()

contents = strio.getvalue()
strio.close() is the way to do it.